# Custom field (date) formatting issue in mailpoet emails

Tags: css, shortcode

In my form is a custom field to allow for a date to be picked, not just today etc., which has the shortcode [subscriber:cf7]. The input is day,month,year.

In the email that is sent this shortcode displays (eg.) 2010-11-26 00:00:00.

I cannot find anywhere to format the output of the custom field to eliminate the time element, or to format the date into dd-mm-yyyy.

Any help with either the settings of mailpoet, or inserting css to over come this would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried several css snippets trying to resolve the issue, but nothing seems to change the output in the email.

I have tried to format the shortcode that is pasted in the email template within mailpoet eg. [subscriber:cf_7 | date:custom | format:l jS F Y], but that didn't help either.